# Does the C compiler combine if statements if they return the same thing?

Tags: c, if-statement, compiler-optimization, c99

I'm trying to understand how a compiler will optimize two if statements that return the same value. Consider the following code at the top of a function:

```
if (some_ptr == NULL) {
    return -1;
}

if (some_other_ptr == NULL) {
    return -1;
}
```

Will the two if statements be combined into one check that is equivalent to:

```
if (some_ptr == NULL || some_other_ptr == NULL) {
    return -1;
}
```

Comment: Why don't you check?

Comment: C will guarantee equivalent evaluation and results because it guarantees short-circuit  boolean evaluation. Whether a compiler would or would not produce identical code is entirely implementation dependent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While the comments emphasize that this behavior is compiler implementation dependent, a look at a specific compiler is helpful in understanding this.

Using the test program:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    srand(time(NULL));

    char *some_ptr = (char *) rand();
    char *some_other_ptr = (char *) rand();

    if (some_ptr == NULL) {
        return -1;
    }

    if (some_other_ptr == NULL) {
        return -1;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Using clang on my laptop running OS X, with no optimization (-O0 flag) the assembly output follows the input code closely with no shortcuts.

```
    movslq  %eax, %rcx
    movq    %rcx, -32(%rbp)
    cmpq    $0, -24(%rbp)
    jne LBB0_2
## BB#1:
    movl    $-1, -4(%rbp)
    jmp LBB0_5
LBB0_2:
    cmpq    $0, -32(%rbp)
    jne LBB0_4
## BB#3:
    movl    $-1, -4(%rbp)
    jmp LBB0_5
LBB0_4:
    movl    $0, -4(%rbp)
LBB0_5:
    movl    -4(%rbp), %eax
    addq    $32, %rsp
    popq    %rbp
    retq
    .cfi_endproc
```

But compiling with the highest optimization (-O3 flag) results in some different code.

```
    movl    %eax, %ecx
    movl    $-1, %eax
    testl   %ebx, %ebx
    je  LBB0_2
## BB#1:
    cmpl    $1, %ecx
    sbbl    %eax, %eax
LBB0_2:
    addq    $8, %rsp
    popq    %rbx
    popq    %rbp
    retq
    .cfi_endprocemphasized text
```

In either case, in the case of my version of clang, the compiler does not ever or the two boolean results together, and even in the optimized code, two comparisons are being made via the `testl` and `cmpl` instructions.

You could write a compiler that has this behavior if you wanted to!